# Handling Exception in Function

Tags: json, error-handling, rx-java

I stumbled over this problem. Lets say i have an Func1 which parses some json string and returns the ServerState (Enum). For some reason the state cant be unknown by the Client or the JSON is bad for some reason.

How do i propagate the Exception from call Method ?

```
public static class ParseProgressFunction implements Func1<String, Observable<ServerState>> {


    @Override
    public Observable<ServerState> call(String progress) {
        try {
            final ServerState serverState = ServerParser.parseProgress(progress);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownServerStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Idea i like to implement this:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveServerState(final Observable<String> state) {
    state.flatMap(new ParseProgressFunction());
```

There must be some best practice, right ?

Happy Easter

Answer (score 1):

As your function return an Observable, you can return a new error Observable with your exception.

```
return Observable.error(you exception);
```